# Seventh day Adventists...will the saved ultimately take on a new form in the kingdom of God?

Tags: soteriology, kingdom-of-god, seventh-day-adventists

What is the SDA explanation of the following.

1 Corinthians 15:49-50 states:

> And just as we have borne the image of the earthly man, so shall we bear the image of the heavenly man.
>   50 I declare to you, brothers and sisters, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable.

We as Christians pray for Gods kingdom to come {Matthew 6:10}; but if flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom as is stated in 1st Corinthians above; does this not then logically mean the saved will have to take on another form?

Comment: In order to work here, your question would have to specify a group or denomination of Christians whose answer you want. As it is now, there could be many different answers depending on the perspective of the answerer—which isn't what this site is for. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry Lee.  You must get fed up posting the same comment ha ha.  I have made the question specific towards the SDA church; hopefully this question will now work.

Comment: Thanks. Your question is now on-topic, and I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: Cheers Lee.  sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is directly answered by Paul in the following verses through an anlalogy.

> 51 Behold! I tell you a mystery. We shall not all sleep, but we shall all
>   be changed, 52in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last
>   trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised
>   imperishable, and we shall be changed. 53For this perishable body must
>   put on the imperishable, and this mortal body must put on immortality.
>   54When the perishable puts on the imperishable, and the mortal puts on
>   immortality, then shall come to pass the saying that is written:

This passage completes the analogy, which is that of redemption through Jesus Christ. When Paul says that 'flesh and blood can not inherit the kingdom of God' he is referring to sinful creation.  However through redemption that is when in the mortal body can put on immortality.

Body and spirit are important theological components, and these components are combined by God in the creative act in Genesis 2. Where God breathed into the man and he became a living thing.  That is, Body and Spirit were combined.